# event.detail.fieldName is undefined when sorting lightning-datatable with custom cell datatypes

Tags: lightning-datatable

I'm using custom datatypes in lightning-datatable which I'd like to sort on. However all the custom types have fieldName undefined when clicking on table headers.

Example header:

```
const STUDENT_COLUMNS = [
    {
        type: 'button-icon',
        initialWidth: 50,
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Assign',
            name: ACTION_ASSIGN,
            title: 'Assign',
            disabled: false,
            value: ACTION_ASSIGN,
            iconPosition: 'left',
            iconName: 'utility:add',
            variant: 'neutral'
        }
    },
    {
        label: '',
        hideDefaultActions: true,
        sortable: true,
        type: 'jobMatchScore',
        initialWidth: 70,
        typeAttributes: {score: {fieldName: 'jobMatchScore'}}
    },
    {
        label: 'Name',
        type: 'infoPopover',
        typeAttributes: {student: {fieldName: 'student'}},
        sortable: true,
        hideDefaultActions: true
    },
```

Example results:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide a `fieldName` attribute at the top level of your column definition, even if you plan on using `typeAttributes`.

```
const STUDENT_COLUMNS = [
    {
        type: 'button-icon',
        initialWidth: 50,
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Assign',
            name: ACTION_ASSIGN,
            title: 'Assign',
            disabled: false,
            value: ACTION_ASSIGN,
            iconPosition: 'left',
            iconName: 'utility:add',
            variant: 'neutral'
        }
    },
    {
        label: '',
        hideDefaultActions: true,
        sortable: true,
        type: 'jobMatchScore',
        initialWidth: 70,
        fieldName: 'jobMatchScore',
        typeAttributes: {score: {fieldName: 'jobMatchScore'}}
    },
    {
        label: 'Name',
        type: 'infoPopover',
        typeAttributes: {student: {fieldName: 'student'}},
        fieldName: 'student',
        sortable: true,
        hideDefaultActions: true
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the one!